# How to retrieve last login for each user from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to cross-reference two tables in my SQL Server database to retrieve a list of all users and the last version of the application they logged in to.

Suppose I have a simple `USERS` table:

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | jackson |
| 23 | fortney |
| 76 | westington |
| 88 | williams |

And a `LOG` table:

| event_id | event_type_id | user_id | created_at | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 23 | 2021-01-01 | 1.2 |
| 2 | 5 | 13 | 2021-05-21 |  |
| 3 | 5 | 76 | 2021-05-21 |  |
| 4 | 4 | 13 | 2021-06-05 | 1.2 |
| 5 | 5 | 23 | 2021-06-15 | 1.2 |

How can I write a SQL query that will return a list of all `USERS` along with their `last_login` date and `version`?  The following should be the result:

| user_name | last_login | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jackson | 2021-06-05 | 1.2 |
| fortney | 2021-06-15 | 1.2 |
| westington | 2021-05-21 | - |
| williams | - | - |

---

I have tried to use a `GROUP BY` clause to isolate each user from the `LOG` table, but SQL Server does not allow grouping by a single field:

```
select u.user_name, l.created_at, version
from USERS u
         join LOG l on u.USER_ID = l.USER_ID
group by u.USERNAME;
```

Comment: What event type is login?

Comment: Ah right. It's 5. I accepted the answer below but modified it to include a `WHERE` clause on `event_type_id`. Thank you, @JoelCoehoorn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select u.user_name, l.created_at, version 
from  users u
outer apply (
   select top 1 * from logs l where u.USER_ID = l.USER_ID
   order by created_at desc 
) l
```

or you can use window function :

```
select * from 
users u
join (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by USER_ID order by created_at desc) rn
   from LOG) l
on u.USER_ID = l.USER_ID
and l.rn = 1
```

Comment: My experience is the `row_number()` version tends to run faster, but I find the `apply` option more natural and easier to write.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `row_number` is generally faster when the majority of the inner table is being selected, or when it is poorly indexed. But when a small number of rows is needed, and the inner table is indexed on the join condition and the ordering column (in that order) then apply will usually be faster